# journald to rsyslog paging issues

Tags: rsyslog, systemd-journald

I'm using rsyslog to dump journald entries to a log file so that they can be sent to Logstash. The issue I'm having is that some of the log lines are getting split across two lines.

When viewing them through journalctl I can use the --no-pager switch to disable this behavior but I haven't been able to find a way to enable this for the log lines being sent to rsyslog.

My journald configuration is just the default. 
My rsyslog configuration for this particular program is as follows

```
$template cleanForm, "%msg%\n"
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate cleanForm

if $programname == 'program-name' then /var/log/program-name.log
if $programname == 'program-name' then ~
```

Comment: What version of systemd? I don't know if this is your problem, but there was a [patch](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/ec20fe5ffb8a00469bab209fff6c069bb93c6db2) to add `LineMax=` to `journald.conf` to not split incoming log streams at 2k bytes.

Comment: @meuh I'm on systemd 229 and they added that flag in update 235 it looks like. I'm going to see if I can update and hopefully that will fix the issue. Thanks!